# Were there any casualties in Thor's fight in London?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, thor-the-dark-world

During *Thor: The Dark World*, Thor and Malekeith engage in a fight that destroys part of London. But in *Captain America: Civil War*, it wasn't listed amongst the causality list that Secretary Ross was showing to the Avengers. Was this because there were no casualties?

Comment: It looked like some people suffered some injuries from flying glass but I can't see any (likely) on-screen deaths.

Comment: Plus that one woman on the tube was basically just pretty happy she got to meet Thor.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Was she a casualty *of passion*?

Comment: I had a look at the transcript for AOS S1E8 which starts off in the aftermath of the Greenwich University battle. No mention about casualties from that battle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no likely human deaths on screen, most of the action takes place away from them. The only injuries there are seem to be from flying glass from when all the windows smash in the building.

---

<sub>*Can’t really provide evidence for this as it’s hard to prove a negative.*</sub>